# xhtml rendered to pdf with base64 img src

Tags: xhtml2pdf, xhtmlrenderer

I am trying to create PDF which should contain image, but does not. The xhtml that is converting to PDF contains img tag with correct base64 data, because when I try it in any html I see correct content. I am using core-renderer R8 version. I kinda suspect that might be a problem because it is 8 years old.

This is the sample that is correctly set in xhtml content.

```
<tr>
    <span>Some info text...</span>
    <img alt="some QR Code" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
</tr>
```

You can check by yourself in any html doc that it generates picture of QR code.

Comment: Is this supposed to be the actual XHTML? It isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys, solution is simple, so if you are using prehistoric core-renderer R8 rather update to flying-saucer renderer which solved my problem